# Twitter api, changing the via name?

Tags: php, twitter

I was wondering when you update a status using twitter api, can I change the name of the via text, i.e. via android, or via facebook, or does twitter only allow one name for each app!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the name of your app on http://dev.twitter.com/apps/